# Google Drive Tool That Can Update The indexableText attribute Of Files

Tags: api, text-processing, google-apps, google-drive, scripting

TLDR: Google Drive does not index markdown files or mime type text/markdown by default. But Google Drive provides a method to index files with mime types that are not indexed by default by updating the indexableText attribute via the Google Drive API.

I'm looking for a tool such as gdrive or a script that can leverage this method to set all files in a specified directory as indexable by Google Drive.

I've reviewed the command line parameters of gdrive and it does not appear to have a reference to indexableText or anything related to index in general.

Background on the problem:

I have applications on Windows desktop and Android mobile such as Obsidian and Markor that saves markdown document files (.md) to a Google Drive folder with a mime type of text/markdown.

When I attempt to search for terms in the content of the markdown files from the Google Drive website, they do not appear to have been indexed and cannot be found. I can only find terms in the filename of the markdown files.

I can create a text document (.txt) with the same content as the markdown file and they are saved to Google Drive with a mime type of text/plain. The content of these text files are indexed and can be found using search on the Google Drive website.

I came across the following article indicating that there is a way via the Google Drive API/SDK to mark a special Google Drive attribute called indexableText to 'true' for mime types that are not indexed by default by Google Drive.

https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/how-to-make-files-searchable-in-google.html

It states, "We recently added a way for you to indicate that the file you are uploading is using a readable text format,".

The excerpt indicates that this method is meant to be used as the files are being uploaded.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to set the indexableText attribute to 'true' on existing files or after the files have already been uploaded, and if there is a tool that does this?

My goal is to have a script that is either triggered by the creation of a new file or that runs at regularly scheduled intervals to make sure that all files in a specified directory are being indexed by Google Drive.

If there are already apps, scripts or services that provide this functionality, I would welcome your recommendations.